# How to update database table and change the button using ajax php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a button named Finish Payment in my page:

```
<button style="background-color:#73bd5a; color:#FFF;" id="finish_payment" 
name="finish_payment" type="button" class="btn btn-white active pull-right">
<i class="ion-checkmark-circled"></i></i> Finish Payment</button>
```

What I want to do is when I click this button I want to update the payment status "Unpaid" to "Paid" in table client_payment and after updating change the button text to paid without refreshing the page. The ajax code I have used is given below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
         $(document).on('click', '.finish_payment', function(){  

       $.ajax({  
            url:"update_payment.php?id=<?php echo $client_id; ?>",  
            method:"POST",  
            dataType:"json",  
            success:function(data){  
              alert(data);  
            }  
       });  
  });
```

And the server side code I have is:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bn");
 $client_id=$_GET['id'];

 $query="update client_payment set payment_status='true' where 
  client_id=$client_id";
 if(mysqli_query($connection, $query)){

echo"Payment Complete";
}
```

Comment: So what is not working? Not updating the db value or not getting button text changed?

Comment: are you getting any error? check your browser console.

Comment: no not any error...

Answer (score 0):

Change your update query like this:

```
$query="update client_payment set payment_status='true' where 
  client_id='".$client_id."'";  // `'` was missing in where clause.
```

And to update button text, you can do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on('click', '#finish_payment', function(){  // finish_payment is id attribute not class. So using with #

     $.ajax({  
        url:"update_payment.php?id=<?php echo $client_id; ?>",  
        method:"POST",  
        dataType:"json",  
        success:function(data){  
            $('.finish_payment').text('Paid');    // Changing button text here.
        }  
   });
```

Comment: ok, so what is the issue? can you repond to my comment _ 
So what is not working? Not updating the db value or not getting button text changed?_

Comment: I just need to update database and the button text to paid...that's it..

Comment: DB is not being changed? Are you getting any error?

Comment: please review the ajax part of code...I think I missed something there...

Comment: he is passing `id` in url too

Comment: Oh man, @RajKumar, you do not have class attribute with `finish_payment` with your button. Its `id` so change your selector with `#`. 
I am going to update my answer.

Comment: did you confirm that the request is coming to the php file? Can you check request in network tab of browser's developer console?

Comment: I think there is error in code,,,no request in network tab of browsers as well...

Comment: I think the `click` function is not being called. Can you alert something as a first line of `$(document).on('click', '#finish_payment', function()`? I doubt that this is not being invoked even.